# Insert an image to a bookmark and resize

Tags: vba, image, ms-word, image-resizing

I am trying to insert and resize an image in word 2019 using vba. I have lot of images to insert and using vba will save a lot of time.

The issue is that I can select the image, but the height does not change. I am sure it is something pretty basic that I am doing wrong. The code, which I found online and I have adjusted a little, is below and any advice would be great. Thank you.

```
Sub insertimage()

On Error Resume Next
' InsertPic Macro
Dim FD As FileDialog
Dim strPictureFile As String
Dim wrdDoc As Word.Document
Dim ishp As Word.InlineShapes


Set FD = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
With FD
    .Title = "Select the Picture that you wish to insert."
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Pictures", "*.jpg; *.bmp; *.gif"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show = -1 Then
        strPictureFile = .SelectedItems(1)
    
    Else
        MsgBox "You did not select a Picture."
        Exit Sub
    End If
End With
Set wrdDoc = ActiveDocument
With wrdDoc
    If .Bookmarks.Exists("BasketIso1") Then
        .InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:=strPictureFile, LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True, Range:=.Bookmarks("BasketIso1").Range
        .InlineShapes(1).LockAspectRatio = True
        .InlineShapes(1).Height = InchesToPoints(1.78)
    
    End If

End With

End Sub
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You seem to see the picture being inserted, which suggests that the code up to and including .AddPicture works OK.

But then you are referencing the *first* picture in the document via .InlineShapes(1) (i.e. that does not reference the first picture in the bookmarks range). If it isn't actually the first picture, another picture will be resized (and you may not notice if it is already set to that size.

So you could redefine the type of `ishp`, which you don't seem to use at present, using

```
Dim ishp As Word.InlineShape
```

then use

```
Set ishp = .InlineShapes.AddPicture(FileName:=strPictureFile, LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True, Range:=.Bookmarks("BasketIso1").Range)
ishp.LockAspectRatio = True
ishp.Height = InchesToPoints(1.78)
Set ishp = Nothing
```

or a variation on that, e.g.

```
Set ishp = .InlineShapes.AddPicture(FileName:=strPictureFile, LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True, Range:=.Bookmarks("BasketIso1").Range)
With ishp
  .LockAspectRatio = True
  .Height = InchesToPoints(1.78)
End With    
Set ishp = Nothing
```

or the

```
With .InlineShapes.AddPicture(FileName:=strPictureFile, LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True, Range:=.Bookmarks("BasketIso1").Range)
  .LockAspectRatio = True
  .Height = InchesToPoints(1.78)
End With
```

NB, probably not a problem in this case but using a generic

```
On Error Resume Next
```

when debugging can make it harder to see the cause of an error.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, it worked a treat and it is really appreciated. I have spent ages trying to get it to work.

Comment: When an answer is helpful, please remember to give it an upvote.